# GridView sorting in UpdatePanel inside UserControl

Tags: asp.net, gridview, user-controls, viewstate

I did find similar questions, but no conclusive answer.

If I put a `GridView` inside an `UpdatePanel`, everything works fine.
However, if I have it inside a `UserControl` like `<UserControl><UpdatePanel><GridView></..>`,
sorting by clicking the headers on the GridView doesn't work anymore (nothing happens).

I can of course handle sorting manually (maintaining a `ViewState` manually), but is that really the only way?

Is GridView inside UpdatePanels inside UserControls simply not supported?

**ASPX-page:**

```
<%@ Register src="usercontrols/MyModule.ascx" TagPrefix="mm" TagName="MyModule" %>
...
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"/>
        <mm:MyModule runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**UserControl:**

```
...
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    ....
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewData" runat="server"
        GridLines="None"
        CssClass="gridview"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        AllowPaging="false"
        AllowSorting="true"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
        ShowFooter="true"
        OnSorting="GridViewData_Sorting">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MyHeader" SortExpression="dbMyColumn">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("dbMyColumn") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The GridViewData_Sorting method doesn't do anything interesting for this issue.

Comment: You should show us at least your UpdatePanel. Does it have [`ChildrenAsTriggers=true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx)?

Comment: should not be related with the UpdatePanel. Could you remove the update panel and see if works as expected?

Comment: Tim: Sorry, I actually expected the answer to be a simple "not supported". I have updated the post.

Comment: Be aware that unfortunately I mixed things - I have changed the post: The UpdatePanel is inside the UserControl, not the other way around as it first said.

Comment: Tim: Even without ChildrenAsTriggers, the UpdatePanel postback is triggered, it just doesn't change anything on the page.

Comment: Claudio: Correct, removing the updatepanel, and it still doesn't work